# How to retain the variable name when sorting a list?

Tags: python, sorting

e.g.:

```
a = 1
b = 3
c = 2
```

I'd like to sort these numerically and obtain a list of the variables in the same order, e.g. the output would be something like `[a,c,b]`

Edit: I'd like to retain the variable names superimposed on the variable values, i.e. I'd like a list sorted by the variable values but that only contains the variable names, e.g. so these would output `[a,c,b]` according to the sorting of their value.

Comment: Variables names don't exist as data in your code. Sorting `[a, b, c]` just sorts the list `[1, 3, 2]`, with no reference to the names used to define the list.

Comment: If you care about the names, use a `dict`: `d = {'a': 1, 'b': 3, 'c': 2}`. Then you can write `sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x:x[1])` to get `[('a', 1), ('c', 2), ('b', 3)]`.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience it's best to think of variable names as non-existent <sup>1</sup>. They just provide *a means for the programmer* to access the value that is *currently* referred to by the variable name.

I can highly recommend [Ned Batchelders blog post on "Facts and myths about Python names and values"](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html) it contains a lot of useful advise on how to think about names and values - even though most of it only tangentially relates to the question.

It seems like what you really want is a name (string) to value (integer) mapping. So I would use a dictionary with strings as keys and the integers as values:

```
d = {'a': 1, 'b': 3, 'c': 2}
```

Then if you want to get a list of the names sorted by the values, you could use:

```
>>> [key for (key, value) in sorted(d.items(), key=lambda key_value: key_value[1])]
['a', 'c', 'b']

>>> sorted(d.items(), key=lambda key_value: key_value[1])
[('a', 1), ('c', 2), ('b', 3)]
```

---

<sup>1</sup> Variable names do exist (as strings) in `globals` or `locals` - but they may contain more names than you (explicitly) used:

```
>>> a = 1
>>> globals()
{'__name__': '__main__', '__doc__': None, ... 'a': 1}
>>> globals()['a']
1
>>> a = 2
>>> globals()['a']
2
```

But except in highly specialized cases accessing `globals` and `locals` is a really bad code smell. **Avoid using `globals` and `locals` whenever possible!**

Answer (score -1):

```
a = 1
b = 3
c = 2
numbers = [a, b, 4, c] 
# Sorting list of Integers in ascending
numbers.sort() 
print(numbers) 

>>>[1,2,3,4]
```

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-list-sort/

Comment: How does this tell the OP what order the variable *names* got sorted in?

Comment: list_name.sort(reverse=True)
This will sort the given list in descending order.

Comment: Sorting is not the issue. Retaining the variable names is.